# Wrong "probability of meeting" intuition

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, intuition

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498359/probability-of-meeting)

Can someone help me understand why the following geometric intuition is wrong?
[Graph with geometric intuition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXZe6.png)

The setup is the same, where we let x and y be the arrival times of A and B. Then, we condition on the arrival time of A: whenever A arrives, for them to meet, B has to arrive at most 10 minutes later. Therefore, the region is bounded by the equations

$$
x = y
$$
$$
x + 10 = y
$$
$$
0 ≤ x ≤ 60
$$
$$
0 ≤ y ≤ 60
$$

I can't find the flaw in this, but it doesn’t give the same result as the linked answer.

Comment: You're missing one of the two ways a meeting could occur (which is why you get half of the area).  You say that whenever A arrives, we need B to arrive at most 10 minutes later.  But it would work just as well if B arrives up to 10 minutes earlier.  So $x=y$ is not the boundary at all; it's $x-10=y$ (along with $x+10=y$, which you have).