# Combined probability distribution function of two uniformly distributed random variable.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I was solving a uniform probability distribution question, the question was : $\\$ *probability of meeting two people A and B between 1 PM and 2 PM, if none of them waits more than 15 minutes for the other.* *Given that probability of arrival is uniform between 1 PM to 2 PM for both of them.*

I took the time span as L and separated two zones. [0,3L/4] and [3L/4,L].

In the first zone if A comes first at time x B has the option to come anytime in [x,x+L/4].
In the second zone,if A comes first at x then B must come in [x,L-x].

I did the integration in two zones and found P(A-B) = 7/32,and multiplied by 2 gives the total probability.

Later I framed (visualized) the same question as follows :
In Cartesian co-ordinate system,along the x axis two points p and q are selected uniformly at random in $\left [ 0,L \right ]$ where L > 0.What is the probability of $\text{dist(p,q)} \leq \frac{L}{4}$.

Then I modified it to two dimensional geometry problem :

In the Cartesian plane, selection of a point P along the y axis in [0,2] is uniformly random. Similarly selection of a point Q along the x axis in [0,2] also uniformly distributed. What is the probability of the area of the triangle POQ to be less than or equal to 1, where O is the origin ?

I solved it using integration in two parts:

- if x is in [0,1] then y is allowed to have the full range of [0,2]
- if x is in [1,2] then y is allowed to have the range [0,2/x]

I got probability as 0.846.

My questions are:

- Is it correct ?
- What is the more generic way to to such problem ? In both the above cases I drew some geometry and did some integration. In the second problem, we are interested in the quantity area (xy/2). But what if we are given a random expression like (3xy+x^2). Please elaborate any other method.

Comment: I do not know much but, is there any connection to convolution of probability density functions to above problems ?

Comment: Effectively the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103015/chance-of-meeting-in-a-bar

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.SE and Math.SE: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/63488/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1927791/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $x$ and $y$ are independent and uniformly distributed
so that geometrically the event space is represented by a square $1\;h\; \times \,1\;h$
of uniform density.
The condition for the meeting to take place is.

$$
\left| {y - x} \right| \leqslant 1/4
$$
i.e.
$$
0 \leqslant y - x \leqslant 1/4\quad  \vee \quad  - 1/4 \leqslant y - x < 0
$$
or
$$
x \leqslant y \leqslant x + 1/4\quad  \vee \quad x - 1/4 \leqslant y < x
$$
which is the area in yellow in the sketch.
[image: Pmeet]

The probability of meeting is easily calculable as:
$$
P_{\text{meet}}  = 1 - 2\frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{3}
{4}} \right)^2  = \frac{7}
{{16}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your description is *very* hard to follow, but I *think* it looks correct.

---

By integration did you do?:
$$\begin{align}P ~=~& \int_1^2\int_{\max(1,a-1/4)}^{\min(2,a+1/4)} f_{\scriptsize A,B}(a,b) \operatorname d b\operatorname d a
\\[1ex] =~& \int_1^{1+1/4}\int_{1}^{a+1/4} 1 \operatorname d b\operatorname d a+\int_{1+1/4}^{2-1/4}\int_{a-1/4}^{a+1/4} 1 \operatorname d b\operatorname d a+\int_{2-1/4}^2\int_{a-1/4}^{2} 1 \operatorname d b\operatorname d a
\end{align}$$

Or via complements:
$$\begin{align}P ~=~&  1-\int_1^{2-1/4}\int_{a+1/4}^2f_{\scriptsize A,B}(a,b) \operatorname d b\operatorname d a-\int_{1+1/4}^2\int_1^{a-1/4}f_{\scriptsize A,B}(a,b) \operatorname d b\operatorname d a
\end{align}$$

---

Geometrically:

Draw a square, $[1;2]^2$.  On it mark lines $\overline{(0,\tfrac 14)(2-\tfrac 14,1)}$ and $\overline{(\tfrac 14,0)(1,2-\tfrac 14)}$.  The proportionate area of the enscribed hexagon is the measure you seek.

$$P=(2-\tfrac 14)(\tfrac 14) = \tfrac 7{16}$$

---

In the second problem you do indeed seek  $$\begin{align}
\iint_{x\in(0;2),y\in(0;2),xy\leq 2} \tfrac 14\operatorname d(x,y) ~=~& \int_0^2\int_{0}^{\min(2,2/x)}\tfrac 14\operatorname d y\operatorname d x
\\ =~& \int_0^1\int_0^2\tfrac 14\operatorname d y\operatorname d x+\int_1^2\int_0^{2/x}\tfrac 14\operatorname d y\operatorname d x\\~=~&\tfrac 12+\tfrac 12\ln 2 \\\approx~& 0.846573590279972654708616060729088284037750067180
\end{align}$$