# What is the probability that the witches will meet at the coffee shop?

Tags: probability, puzzle, conditional-probability, density-function

I am trying to solve this [probability question](https://brainstellar.com/puzzles/30):

> Two witches make a nightly visit to an all-night coffee shop. Each arrives at a random time between 0:00 and 1:00. Each one of them stays for exactly 30 minutes. On any one given night, what is the probability that the witches will meet at the coffee shop?

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680/probability-that-two-people-see-each-other-at-the-coffee-shop) but I am trying to work out on this problem using a different approach than the one mentioned in above link that is a graph based approach (the same approach is also mentioned in the link to the question) and couldn't find mistake in my approach. Here is what I did:

> Let $U_1$ be a random variable denoting the arrival time of first witch and let $U_2$ be the random variable denoting the arrival time of second witch. Both $U_1$ and $U_2$ follows Uniform Distribution i.e.
>   $U_1 $~$ Uniform(0, 1)$ and $U_2 $~$ Uniform(0, 1)$ where I have mapped time `0:00` to $0$ and time `1:00` to $1$.
>
> Now we have to find out $P(|U_1-U_2| \leqslant \frac12)$
>
> $$=> P(\frac{-1}2 \leqslant U_1-U_2 \leqslant \frac12) = \int_0^1 P[(\frac{-1}2 \leqslant U_1-U_2 \leqslant \frac12)|U_1=x]*f_{U_1}(x) dx$$
>
> $$=\int_0^1 P[(\frac{-1}2 \leqslant x-U_2 \leqslant \frac12)|U_1=x]*f_{U_1}(x) dx$$
>
> $$=\int_0^1 P[(\frac{-1}2-x \leqslant -U_2 \leqslant \frac12-x)]*f_{U_1}(x) dx$$
>
> $$=\int_0^1 P[(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2 \leqslant x+\frac12)]dx$$
>   (Since $f_{U_1}(x)$ is pdf of Uniform distribution so it is $1$)
>
> $$=\int_0^\frac 12 P(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2 \leqslant x+\frac12)dx+\int_\frac 12^1 P(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2 \leqslant x+\frac12)dx$$
>
> $$=\int_0^\frac 12 P(U_2 \leqslant x+\frac12)dx+\int_\frac 12^1 P(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2)dx$$
>   (Since in range $[0,\frac 12]$, $x-\frac 12 \in [\frac{-1}2,0]$ and $U_2 \geqslant 0$ and similarly, in range $[\frac12, 1]$, $x+\frac 12 \in [1, \frac 32]$ and $U_2 \leqslant 1$)
>
> $$=\int_0^\frac 12 (x+\frac 12)dx+\int_\frac 12^1 (\frac 12-x)dx$$
>
> $$[\frac {x^2}2+\frac x2]_0^\frac 12+[\frac x2-\frac {x^2}2]_\frac12^1$$
>
> $$=\frac 12[\frac 14+\frac 12]+\frac 12[(1-1)-(\frac 12 -\frac 14)]$$
>   $$=\frac 12[\frac 34]+\frac 12[-\frac 14]$$
>   $$=\frac 38 - \frac 18$$
>   $$=\frac 14$$

But the correct answer is $\frac 34$. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Good work, mostly.  A bell should have gone off when your $\int_{1/2}^1$ turned out to be negative (since it the integral of a strictly non-negative function).  Indeed your arithmetic error is just that $1-\left(x-\frac 12\right)=\frac 32-x$, not $\frac 12-x$.

Comment: That was a very cruel mistake :) I was looking at whole derivation again and again to see if I made some conceptual mistake but that was it. But "A bell should have gone off ...." is a very nice observation and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arithmetic error is in the second integral.  Indeed,

$$\int_\frac 12^1 P(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2)dx$$ is clearly positive since it is the integral of a non-negative function.

We see that

$$\int_\frac 12^1 P(x-\frac{1}2 \leqslant U_2)dx=\int_{\frac 12}^1 1-\left(x-\frac 12\right)\,dx=\int_{\frac 12}^1\left(\frac 32-x\right)\,dx=\frac 38$$