# How to find a probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Imagine some kind of tape and its length equals to 2 meter. And we're going to write some data from **any point of the tape to any point of the tape** with the length of 68 centimeter. After writing first data,we need to write second data with the same length from **any point of the tape to any point of the tape**. The question is what is the probability that two data could be intersected?(in other words, can have common point). **NOTE:** This task is solved through continuous random variable.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Looks like a "two friends agree to meet" type question such as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103015/chance-of-meeting-in-a-bar

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Suppose we pick some subset $[x,x+.68] \subseteq [0,2]$ and some other subset $[y,y+.68] \subseteq [0,2]$. That restricts $(x,y) \in [0,1.32]^2$. Let $y \geq x$. Note then the two subsets intersect if and only if $y  \leq x+.68$.