Probability that random calls are made within 5 minutes of each other
Problem from statistics textbook:
Two telephone calls come into a switchboard at random times in a fixed one-hour period. Assume that the calls are made independently of one another. What is the probability that the calls are made
a. in the first half hour?
Answer: $\frac{1}{4}$
b. within five minutes of each other?
Answer: $\frac{23}{144}$
As it is given that they are independent, I was able to calculate part a by simply performing $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$. However, I am struggling to derive an approach for the latter half of this question. Intuitively, I think of approaching it as an integral with some bounds constrained +/- 5 minutes, but I struggle to come up with values, as well as the joint probability function (which should, I believe, be uniform). Would greatly appreciate some assistance

Imagine plotting the two call times as $(x,y)$ coordinates in a square, and find the area of the region corresponding to the event in question.

I don't entirely follow --
Here's what I've (unsuccessfully) now tried:
thinking of the whole area as a square, the denominator becomes 60x60 = 3600. I then thought of this region as the double integral between 0 and 60 (outer) and (x-5) and (x+5) (inner).

When you are imagining the problem as a square, then $x$-axis represents the time of the first call and $y$-axis represents that of the second call. Thus, you are interested in the region $|x -y| \leq 5$, not $x - 5$ and $x + 5$. This graph might be helpful to visualize the area.

Got it, I wasn't accounting for the triangular "tip region" of the inequality. Adding the area of those and dividing by 3600 gives the valid answer

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103015/chance-of-meeting-in-a-bar and the pages that link to it
